# Expectation of the loss decrease when adding samples to model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, references

**Context:** Let there be a loss function $L$ that measures the performance of a model. Perhaps the $L_2$ loss: $L(y,w^T x) = (y - w^T x)^2$, for simplicity I take a linear model ($w^Tx$) but it could be any model. $y$ is the output we wish to predict. Assume there is a probability distribution $P(x,y)$. Perhaps the model is regularized, so it minimizes something such as:

$$w^*_N = \underset{w}{\text{argmin}} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(w^Tx_i - y_i\right) + \lambda w^T w$$

**Question:** Is it then possible, or when is it possible, to say that, if we add a sample, that $w_{N+1}^*$ improves upon $w_{N}^*$ in expectation? Thus if the expected loss is given by:

$$R(w) = \int \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(w^Tx_i - y_i\right) P(x,y) dx dy$$

Under what condition is it the case that:

$$R(w_{N+1}^*) \leq R(w_{N}^*) \,\,?$$

This seems like it should be trivial or well known. Perhaps under a different loss, with or without regularization, or under some specific $P(x,y)$?

Comment: I agree that it looks trivial.  Leaving out the new observation will give you a solution that is at least as good as the original (smaller) sample.  *A fortiori*, it's impossible to do any worse when you add a new observation.  Please note that in a regularized model the loss is not $L$: it has been changed to include the penalty.